# How python Create a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

- Myquestion is why when iterating over a dictionary it return only
  key and doesn't return its value is it because how python implement  a    dictionary like it a dictionary is only a list of keys and these keys just point to a different place in meomery ,that the key and its value both have different ID . I am asking this question because when i iterate over a list containing a list the for loop will always return the list that is inside the bigger list like in this example

```
a = [ ['abc'] , [abc] , ['abc'] ]    

for item in a :
   print(item)
```

Comment: Have you heard about `dict.items()` method?

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the intro tour.  Focus each posting on a single question, and make it clear what sort of answer you want.  It would also help to have someone edit your post to clarify the wording.

Comment: Python dictionaries and lists are very different. Dictionaries are implemented as hash tables, and lists are implemented as dynamic arrays.

Comment: Because `dict` objects are maps. Maps don't have indices, they associate keys with values. That's what they do. As for, "why when iterating over a dictionary it return only key" because *that's what the designers of the API decided, it *could* have done something else, or it *could* have simlply been not iterable, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why accessing a key and it's value using an index isn't allowed in python i mean it make sense in this case

You can have a dictionary containing numbers as keys:

```
my_dict = {1: "a", 0: "b", ...}
print(my_dict[0]) # prints 'b', though it's not the first element in the dictionary
```

There would be no way to differentiate "accessing index 0" or "accessing the value with key of 0". If the key is irrelevant and only the order matters, then you don't need a dictionary, you only need a list.

Comment: It also doesn't matter whether the dictionary's contents are ordered or not (so applies to before and after Python version 3.6).

Comment: Tried to make that clear in my example but didn't explicitly say it... whoops.